Not able to send https request with libcurl
I am trying to run below example with libcurl
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
   
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

#ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
        /*
         * If you want to connect to a site who is not using a certificate that is
         * signed by one of the certs in the CA bundle you have, you can skip the
         * verification of the server's certificate. This makes the connection
         * A LOT LESS SECURE.
         *
         * If you have a CA cert for the server stored someplace else than in the
         * default bundle, then the CURLOPT_CAPATH option might come handy for
         * you.
         */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
#endif

#ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION
        /*
         * If the site you are connecting to uses a different host name that what
         * they have mentioned in their server certificate's commonName (or
         * subjectAltName) fields, libcurl refuses to connect. You can skip this
         * check, but it makes the connection insecure.
         */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
#endif

        /* cache the CA cert bundle in memory for a week */
        auto resultThree = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CA_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 604800L);

        /* Perform the request, res gets the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}

but I am getting the response as CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL for curl_easy_perform. It looks like it can not process https response where as http response for "https://example.com/" is all good.
I referred to
Unsupported Protocol using Curl in C
curl -V does show me https and my cmakelist does show below (in block code), so I am sure it is built with SSL Library
if(WIN32)
  cmake_dependent_option(CURL_USE_SCHANNEL "Enable Windows native SSL/TLS" OFF CURL_ENABLE_SSL OFF)
  option(CURL_WINDOWS_SSPI "Enable SSPI on Windows" ${CURL_USE_SCHANNEL})
endif()

Next I have referred to How to Download the SSL Certificate From a Website in Windows and manually downloaded the server certificate as cacert.crt
Then I am trying to use curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, cacert); as suggested in
Certificate Verification and CURLOPT_CAINFO
and accordingly my code looks like
curl = curl_easy_init();
    auto cacert = "C:\\GauravK\\CPP_17\\CURL_CPP\\CURL_CPP\\cacert.crt";
    if (curl) {
        auto resultOne = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, const_cast<char*> (cacert));
        auto resultTwo = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

        /* cache the CA cert bundle in memory for a week */
        auto resultThree = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CA_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 604800L);

        /* Perform the request, res gets the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

resultOne, resultTwo and resultThree are all CURLE_OK, but my res is still CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL.  I even tried to define SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION and SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION but no luck.
Can someone help please?

libcurl that you are using is built without https protocol support.

@273K The source code was downloaded with github and I can see in the cmake where it checks WIN32 option and then below cmake_dependent_option(CURL_USE_SCHANNEL "Enable Windows native SSL/TLS" OFF CURL_ENABLE_SSL OFF) option.  I believe I need to change it to ON ? Is that what you are suggesting ?

After multiple attempts, I was not able to compile the source-code with OpenSSL support with cmake-gui.
With the help from Cmake not able to find openssl library, I did manage to find openSSL, as indicated by below output in cmake-gui output for configure button
Found OpenSSL: D:/OpenSSL/openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32/lib/libeay32.lib (found version "3.3.0")  .
But, when I tried to compile the source code with the generated visual studio 2022 solution, curl and libcurl_shared projects failed.
I did manage to generate libcurl.lib and libcurl_imp.lib but not the dlls. It could be a problem with zlib, as I was getting errors related to it during configure.
Also, it looks like I could not link the sample code statically with the generated libcurl.lib and libcurl_imp.lib, even with the pre-processor keyword CURL_STATICLIB as suggested in unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl.
I did try to install curl with vcpkg with below instructions as mentioned in the doc cUrl Install
Building using vcpkg
You can download and install curl and libcurl using the vcpkg dependency manager:

git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install curl[tool]

It did generate the libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll.
Linking them dynamically to my sample code in VS2022 project, I did manage to get the https response.
